# Big performance difference between using class with static functions vs instantiated class?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3

I'm wondering if anyone has experience with if there is a big difference in performance in ActionScript 3 between keeping a class with only public static functions, and utilizing those functions often (as in a frame event at 30fps), and in turning the class into a "normal" class of which I instead make an instance and call the functions via the instance instead.

Hope I'm explaining myself fairly okay here...

cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According uber AS3 optimiser [Jackson Dunstan](http://jacksondunstan.com/) there is a significant difference, with static methods being about 3 to 4 times slower than non-static methods.

- [Static vs. non-static](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1690)
- [Why static is slow](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1713)

Comment: Thanks mate. Great resources in those blogposts  :-)

Comment: it's worth bearing in mind that that's over a loop of about 100 million :D - Static is slower, yes, but you're unlikely to notice much of a difference in daily use